# uipickerview deselect all items

Tags: iphone, sdk, uipickerview, uipicker

Is it possible to load an uipickerview with values but by default have no item selected?

I tried setting selected item to -1 with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you always have to have at least one item selected with a UIPicker... What would it display? Maybe you could create an item titled, "Please select" or something?

I think that you should always have at least some default that's already selected.

Comment: Yep, what @James said, check in the delegate to see if the "fake" item is selected then do what you need to do to alert the user that they need to pick something else.